# Create signature generated using a private key

Tags: node.js, swift, security, cryptography

I'm trying to port this code from Node.js to Swift. This is for creating a signature from a private key.

The private key is generated using these instructions.

https://walmart.io/key-tutorial

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out WM_IO_my_rsa_key_pair 2048
```

Here is my working Node.js code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require("fs");

(async () => {
    const privateKey = await fs.promises.readFile("./keys/in.pem");
    const string = "Hello World"
    const sign = crypto.createSign('sha256');
    sign.write(string);
    sign.end();

    const signature = sign.sign({ 
        key: privateKey
    }); 

    const signature_enc = signature.toString("base64");
    console.log(signature_enc);
})()
```

This is my attempt in a Swift playground. I'm not able to figure out what signing algorithm to use to create the same signature. I also export the private key from the .pem file using this command for Swift.

```
openssl rsa -in in.pem -out out.pem
```

Here is my Swift code:

```
import UIKit
import Security
import CommonCrypto

func createKey(pem: String) -> SecKey? {
    let attributes: [NSObject : NSObject] = [
       kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
       kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
       kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: NSNumber(value: 2048)
    ]

    let privateKey = pem
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", with: "")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", with: "")
        .split(separator: "\n").joined()

    guard let privateKeyData = Data(base64Encoded: privateKey, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
        return nil
    }

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    return SecKeyCreateWithData(privateKeyData as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, &error)
}

func createHash(string: String) -> Data {
    let hash = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    let hashLength = string.count
    defer { hash.deallocate() }
    CC_SHA256(string, CC_LONG(hashLength), hash)
    return Data(bytes: hash, count: hashLength)
}

let privateKey = """
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"""

if let key = createKey(pem: privateKey) {
    // Create hash
    let hash = createHash(string: "Hello World")
    
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    if let signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(key, .rsaSignatureMessagePKCS1v15SHA256, hash as CFData, &error) as Data? {
        let signiture64 = signature.base64EncodedString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [crypto.createSign](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatesignalgorithm-options) and also checked if `'sha256'` is included in the list returned by `crypto.getHashes()`? Because `sha256` is not a signature scheme, so it may be the truncated (or outdated?) name of `RSA-SHA256`.

Comment: The algorithm applied by `createSign()` depends on the key. Since you are using an RSA key, it will be signed with RSA. PKCS#1 v1.5 is used as padding by default. `SecKeyCreateSignature()` seems to hash *implicitly*. In this case, it's rather the unshashed message that has to be passed and not the hashed one as in the current code.

Comment: By the way, *openssl genrsa -des3...* generates an encrypted RSA key. For this to be read in the NodeJS code, actually the password must be specified in the `sign()` call.

Comment: Thank you @Topaco! That worked by passing the unhashed message!

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if it's possible to pass the encrypted private key (original pem file) with passphrase to Swift?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I' m not very familiar with Swift.

Comment: No worries! Thanks so much for helping me solve that issue. You can write it as an answer so I can except.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dive into the NodeJS crypto code, but I assume it uses the scheme you have in your example, PKCS#1v5 using SHA-256. One of the things I noticed is that you supplied the `.rsaSignatureMessagePKCS1v15SHA256` parameter, which indicates that you want the OS to do the hashing for you, but you did it yourself. Setting it to `.rsaSignatureDigestPKCS1v15SHA256` tells the OS to not do any hashing. In the example I have omitted any manual hashing.

```
import Foundation

let privateKey = """
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"""

func createKey(pem: String) -> SecKey? {
    let derString = pem.split(separator: "\n")
        .dropFirst()
        .dropLast()
        .joined()

    guard let der = Data(base64Encoded: derString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
        return nil
    }

    let attributes: [CFString: Any] = [
       kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
       kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
       kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 2048
    ]

    return SecKeyCreateWithData(der as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, nil)
}

if let key = createKey(pem: privateKey) {
    let message = Data("Hello World".utf8)

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    // signature message automatically hashes the input data, so you don't have to do this manually
    if let signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(key, .rsaSignatureMessagePKCS1v15SHA256, message as CFData, &error) as Data? {
        print(signature.base64EncodedString())
    } else {
        print(error?.takeUnretainedValue())
    }
}
```